# Overlay inside bootstrap col for fullscreen info

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have lots of columns like the following code and what i want is on clicking anywhere on the div below the div of more-info-hidden to be changed to more-info and the whole lorem-ipsum is displayed in whole window with a red background.  my html is as follows, i mainly want help in css.

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
    <figure class="effect-zoe">
        <img src="img/alisha.jpg" alt="img26"/>
        <figcaption>
            <h2>Alisha <span>Abdulah</span></h2>
            <p class="description">PIONEER OF FEMALE CAR AND BIKE RACING IN INDIA AND THE WORLD</p>
        </figcaption>           
        <div class="more-info-hidden">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin urna ligula, hendrerit sed enim non, faucibus sagittis felis. Pellentesque vehicula orci sit amet efficitur bibendum. Duis velit lorem, aliquam non augue eu, lacinia cursus ex. Etiam aliquam commodo tempus. Suspendisse potenti. Curabitur blandit quam dolor, in facilisis quam feugiat eu. Maecenas leo libero, pretium eget arcu in, blandit rhoncus massa. Phasellus sit amet gravida sem. Nulla sit amet tincidunt nisi, et imperdiet nunc. Cras eu turpis ullamcorper, lobortis nisi sit amet, auctor est. In suscipit ornare enim rhoncus sollicitudin. Vivamus metus lectus, blandit non nibh vitae, tempor aliquam elit.
            </p>
        </div>
    </figure>
</div>
```

the javascript of my code is as follows:

```
$('.effect-zoe').click(function(){


        var modal = $(this).children(".more-info-hidden");
        modal.toggleClass("more-info-hidden");
        modal.toggleClass("more-info");

    });
```

and the css would be:

```
.more-info-hidden{
  display: none;
}
.more-info{
  display: block;
  height: 100vh;
  width:100vh;
  background-color: #e62b1e;
}
```

the problem in this css is that it is not showing the more-info although the class is toggled. it is hidden behind the image somewhere inside the bootstrap div but i want it in whole window. 
and PS i have lots of  these cols so i dont want to make the more-info outside as for that i would have to give different classes to all more-info

Answer (score 0):

if the text is hiding behind the image. please try with relative css property.

example:

```css
.image { 
   position: relative; 
   width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
}

h2 { 
   position: absolute; 
   top: 200px; 
   left: 0; 
   width: 100%; 
}
```

```html
<div class="image">

     <img src="images/3754004820_91a5c238a0.jpg" alt="" />
      
     <h2>A Movie in the Park:<br />Kung Fu Panda</h2>

</div>
```

**strong text**